# Insert string to SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, azure

I'm having an issue at the moment which I am trying to fix. I just tried to access a database and insert some values with the help of C#

My code:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.DataSource = "testtetstet.database.windows.net";
builder.UserID = "PW";
builder.Password = "000000000";
builder.InitialCatalog = "test";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.amir (theDate,Hostname,IP) VALUES (@theDate,@hostName, @IP)";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@theDate");
        command.Parameters.Add("@hostName");
        command.Parameters.Add("@IP");

        connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Check Error
        if (result < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, insert 3 strings in to the sql database but it seems that it does not work!!

"@hostname"is a string which contains the computer name
"@IP" is a string which contains the IP adress
"@theDate" is a DateTime string which display date and time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? You're not supplying any values to the parameters you're adding. Try `command.Parameters.Add("@theDate").Value = DateTime.UtcNow`, etc.

Comment: what error/exception you are getting exactly? Please put try catch blocks to handle the exception

Comment: As per John's comment, you probably should read [Msdn SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Parameters)

Comment: @John Correct. You should pass the values. Values may be from textbox or any object. Please check Refer this code:       command.Parameters.Add("@theDate",dateValue);
     command.Parameters.Add("@hostName",hostValue);
     command.Parameters.Add("@IP",IpValue);

Comment: I also suggest setting the sql db type for each parameter.

Comment: Why MySql tag? Azure is a Microsoft product and the code you presented is using  classes from the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace which is only working with Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. @ZoharPeled can you tell me more? (I'm a beginner for C#)

Comment: Tell you more about what, exactly? If you have a specific question, post it like you did this one...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not setting the value of parameter.You should either Use Parametrs.Add like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@IP", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0.0.0.0";
//equals to:
//command.Parameters.Add("@IP", SqlDbType.VarChar); 
//command.Parameters["@IP"].Value = "0.0.0.0";
```

or (not recommended):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP", "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I was just showing possible ways, not recommending one.

Comment: Well, you should be recommending one. After all, we are here to help...

Comment: Thank you Ashkan!

Answer (score 6):

You don't pass any values to the parameters. Try something like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theDate", date);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hostName", host);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP", ip);
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)